# Simulating subclassing in Javascript - check how I've done it?

Tags: javascript, subclass

I'm writing some javascript that's GNOME javascript, which is more-or-less spidermonkey. Think of it as spidermonkey code that will *never* be run outside of spidermonkey, so no need to worry about cross-browser compatibility etc.

Basically I have a class `Folks.Individual` that is *not* subclassable, but I want to simulate subclassing it by just patching it, adding a few getters to it. (For those that are interested, it is a `GObject` obtained via gobject introspection and in my version of GJS you can't subclass a `GObject`).

Notes:

- `contactSys.get_individual(contactID)` returns the `Folks.Individual` I'm patching
- I add some getters `email`, `aliasText`, and `online` that return some values.
- I use this class via `let contact = new Contact(id);`, and simply want to use `contact` as if it were a `Folks.Individual`, plus the extra properties I patch in.
- If the properties I wanted to patch were not dynamic, I'd just do it like so:

  ```
  let contact = contactSys.get_individual(contactID);
  contact.email = ....;
  contact.aliasText = ....;
  contact.online = ....;
  ```

I simply want a convenience function about the above such that I can call `let contact = new Contact(contactID)` and it will return `contact` with the `email`, `aliasText` and `online` properties patched in (as getters though).

This is how I've done it at the moment. My question is, is this the "proper" way to do it? Should I be using `this` instead of `contact` within `Contact()`? Should I be doing something with `Folks.Individual.prototype` instead and calling it a `Contact`?

```
function Contact (contactID) {                                                  
    let contactSys = Shell.ContactSystem.get_default(),                         
        contact    = contactSys.get_individual(contactID); // <-- this is a Folks.Individual
    contact._contactSys = contactSys;                                           

    /* these are defined as getters in case the underlying values change */     
    Object.defineProperty(contact, 'email', {get: function () {                 
        return contact._contactSys.get_email_for_display(this);                 
    }});                                                                        
    Object.defineProperty(contact, 'aliasText', {get: function () {             
        return contact.alias     ||                                             
               contact.full_name ||                                             
               contact.nickname  ||                                             
               contact.email     ||                                             
               _("Unknown");                                                    
    }});                                                                        
    Object.defineProperty(contact, 'online', {get: function () {                
        return contact.presence_type === Folks.PresenceType.AVAILABLE ||        
               contact.presence_type === Folks.PresenceType.AWAY ||             
               contact.presence_type === Folks.PresenceType.EXTENDED_AWAY ||    
               contact.presence_type === Folks.PresenceType.BUSY;               
    }});                                                                        
    return contact;                                                             
}
```

Remember - **I can't subclass Folks.Individual**, so I'll settle for patching instances of it with a wrapper function `new Contact(contactID)` so that I can treat it as if it were a subclass. I just want to know if there's a standard way of doing this.

cheers!

Comment: Looks ok tome. You may also want to cache these augmented objects by contactID

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you can probably do 'online' a bit more succinctly and efficiently:

```
var ONLINE = Folks.PresenceType.AVAILABLE |
              Folks.PresenceType.AWAY |
              Folks.PresenceType.EXTENDED_AWAY |
              Folks.PresenceType.BUSY;

Object.defineProperty(contact, 'online', {
  get: function(){ return (this.presence_type & ONLINE) > 0 }
});
```

Comment: As the `integer` type doesn't not exist in JS (every number is handle as a `float`), using bitwise operators isn't optimal.

Comment: Integers sure do exist in js. Since bitwise operations must return them it's a great way to tell the jit compiler what you're doing. If you want to be more explicit, (and to illustrate ints strictly do exist):  `var coerceToInt = new Int32Array(1); coerceToInt[0] = ONLINE;`; Though that's not really necessary here since the bitwise operations do the job. What's important is what inferences the js engine can make from your code and how reliable they are. (and how optimizable)

Comment: Thanks, that's handy. I have been using bitwise operators elsewhere in my code but for some reason forgot to apply them here (and the flags are designed to be used with bitwise operations too)